# Will two DC DC converters being supplied from the same source have the same ground?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I need a check on my design.
I am designing the voltage section for my board and require two isolated grounds since I am using PC187 optocouplers in my design. In the below block, the grounds of both the DC DC converters will be interconnected, am I correct?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean PC817? Those are themselves isolated. I don't see why that motivates isolated power. Can you show more of your design to illustrate how this is relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those [VR05S05](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_VR05.pdf) devices only have three pins, so the grounds for the input and output must be the same. You would want isolated DC-DC converters.